# Nested Border Container - Programmatic Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to create my page layout using **ONLY** programmatic syntax but I'm not able to insert a Border Container with a left, center and right Content Pane, into the top pane of the main layout (the same goes for the bottom one).

Every time I try to use a Content Pane as a parent, I break the main layout.

I know how to create this layout in a declarative way (in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/_mic_/h4j20rxs/5/) `code` the Accordion Container is inside the right pane of the main Border Container).

But how can I create a nested Border Container with its children inside a Content Pane using only programmatic Dojo?

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/_mic_/htsL77mw/1/) the `code` is slightly different with the Accordion Container by itself with no splitter created in programmatic way)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

mic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't nest a bordercontainer in a contentpane that's a child of a bordercontainer. That's kind of redundant since bordercontainer is a pane itself. If you want to nest bordercontainer can add it directly as a child of the parent container:

```
var main = new BorderContainer({
    'design': 'headline',
    'id': 'main'
});

var top = new BorderContainer({
    'design': 'sidebar',
    'region': 'top',
    'id': 'top',
    'splitter': true
});

main.addChild(top);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3JR6NI?p=preview

Comment: Now I see! Thanks @iH8, using Maqetta to create my first layout in a declarative way made me think I was nesting the Border Container into a Content Pane! I really appreciate your help!